# Converting a string with underscores to TitleCase

Tags: c#, string

Given this string:
  "EMAIL_LOG"

I want to convert it to:
  EmailLog

I have this code that does do the job:

```
private static string TitleCaseConvert(string title)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
    title = title.Replace("_", " ").ToLower();
    title = textInfo.ToTitleCase(title);
    title = title.Replace(" ", "");
    return title;
}
```

I was just wondering if there was a better suggestion to do this conversion or one that was more elegant perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: seems legit. I just dont understand this line : CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; why do we need to talk to the currenthread.currentculture. why isn't it a singleton ?

Comment: `.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("EMAIL_LOG".ToLower()).Replace("_", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing it in one statement, like this:

```
private static string TitleCaseConvert(string title)
{ 
   return new CultureInfo("en").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(title.ToLower().Replace("_", " ")).Replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: This is what I am after, thanks.  I added a second var in the call for a separator and defaulted it to "_".  This gives me the flexibility to pass in whatever separator I need to do this Rename.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Split()` to split on the `_` characters and `StringBuilder` to reconstruct the output string.  This *should* perform better because you are using `StringBuilder` instead of constructing new strings everytime:

```
private static string ToPascalCase(string input)
{
    if(input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }

    TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var part in input.Split('_'))
    {
        sb.Append(textInfo.ToTitleCase(part.ToLower()));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that I am using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` static property.  I think it more accurately describes what you want...

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yozAWJ)

Answer (score 0):

If you're after raw performance, you could operate directly on a char array:

```
private static string TitleCaseConvert(string title)
{
    int wordStart = 0;

    char[] result = new char[title.Length];
    int ri = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < title.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (title[i] == '_')
        {
            wordStart = i + 1;
        }
        else if (i == wordStart)
        {
            result[ri++] = Char.ToUpper(title[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            result[ri++] = Char.ToLower(title[i]);
        }
    }

    return new String(result, 0, ri);
}
```

Otherwise, a `StringBuilder` implementation will probably be shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could toss `Regex.Replace()` at this thing to pick out the first character, dump the underscore, and capitalize it.

```
title = Regex.Replace("this_is_a_test", @"(^|_)([a-z])", m =>  m.ToString().Replace("_","").ToUpper());
```

Comment: This works if I do a ToLower function on the original string EMAIL_LOG.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using `Microsoft.VisualStudio` :

```
var title = Strings.StrConv("EMAIL_LOG", VbStrConv.ProperCase).Replace("_", "");
```

---

Using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#pascalize) library :

```
var title = "EMAIL_LOG".ToLower().Pascalize();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the `_.camelCase` function in any library as `lodash`.

```
_.camelCase("EMAIL_LOG") // "emailLog"
```

We add (also from `lodash`) the `_.upperFirst` function to put the first character in uppercase.

```
_.upperFirst( _.camelCase("EMAIL_LOG") ) // "EmailLog"
```

**Camel Case**

> Camel case is the practice of writing compound words or phrases such
>   that each word or abbreviation in the middle of the phrase begins with
>   a capital letter, with no intervening spaces or punctuation.

**Lodash**

> Lodash is a JavaScript library which provides utility functions for
>   common programming tasks using the functional programming paradigm.